# how to stop to show Remember Password

Tags: webview, passwords, message

I make Application with webview to my Application. when i want to Login some pages and i want to login saites the confirm Message is displayed.and it says that do you want the browser to remember this password. I don't want to show this Message and i dont want to click on never

what should I do to stop showing this Message and what should i do to Not displayed this Message

you can see the see screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kulj.jpg

Comment: It's your user's choice to do that, not yours. Does what you are offering have enough value, for them to want to type in a strong password everytime, or of course to risk using a weak one?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this behavior off with the WebSettings.setSavePassword() API. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSavePassword(boolean)